# I want to print a randomly generated number inside my class but keep getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, random

I am getting a name error, randint not defined when trying to print a random number from a class method.

```
class Deck:
    import random
    def __init__(self,choice,card = 0):
        self.choice = choice
        self.card = card
    def deck(self): 
        if self.choice == 1:
            print((randint(1,5)))
```

I want it to print a random number 1-5, I can achieved the result by creating a class variable with a random number assigned to it, I would still like to know why I can not just generate random numbers inside the methods.

Comment: What about [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#functions-for-integers)?

Comment: random.randint(a,b) gives the same error but says random is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not calling `randint` through `random` module.

The correct way to use `randint` is to either do it through `random` module explicitly.

```
import random

class Deck:
    def __init__(self,choice,card = 0):
        self.choice = choice
        self.card = card
    def deck(self): 
        if self.choice == 1:
            print((random.randint(1,5)))
```

Or by bringing `randint` into your module namespace as in

```
from random import randint

class Deck:
    def __init__(self,choice,card = 0):
        self.choice = choice
        self.card = card
    def deck(self): 
        if self.choice == 1:
            print((randint(1,5)))
```

Comment: Great answer. Note that OP cannot have `import random` in the class definition to fix his issue. Needs to be at the top or in the actual function or method.

Comment: More specifically, even when I had from random import randint int the beginning of the class the method would still say whatever variable was not defined. Does it have anything to do with inheritance?

Comment: That's correct @NicholasP, imports brings in the variable into a scope where they are defined, so functions do not have implicit access to globals available in class scope, which is why you should either import it in a global scope (which is the default and recommended way to import modules) or import it directly in your function, though it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally bad practice to have imports inside of a class, but to use class functions to do it would look like:

```
class Deck:
    random = __import__('random')
    def __init__(self,choice,card = 0):
        self.choice = choice
        self.card = card
    def deck(self): 
        if self.choice == 1:
            print((self.random.randint(1,5)))

x = Deck(choice = 1)
x.deck()
```

Comment: What would be better practice for having it outside of a class then? ** I see someone posted it above, thanks.

Comment: PEP8 prefers imports to be stated at the top of the file, so any requirements are obvious: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports Being that random is a built-in module, you are a little safer importing in a class, verses say PySerial.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement should be outside of the class definition (and preferably at the top of the script, but this is not necessary)

And in order to use the randint function you must call it by first referring to the random library:

```
import random

class Deck:
    def __init__(self,choice,card = 0):
        self.choice = choice
        self.card = card
    def deck(self):
        if self.choice == 1:
            print((random.randint(1,5)))
```